# Bayesian significance test for bin counts with reference probabilities

Tags: statistical-significance, bayesian, contingency-tables

In the software i'm contributing to, there's a procedure to take samples from a certain 2D distribution (if you're curious, it's for sampling a [BSDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_scattering_distribution_function), used in rendering) and a procedure to return the corresponding pdf (over the hemisphere in terms of solid angle measure).

In order to test the implementation of the `sample()` and `pdf()` functions, i want to test if the binned sample counts agree with the bin probabilities $P_i$ i get from the pdf function (by integrating pdf over each bin). Basically i want to compare the two distributions in a significance test way and based on the result, let the unit test for the software pass or fail.

In the literature and similar software projects i mainly see people using Chi-squared tests, which can work to a degree, but produces problems with bins with zero counts or in general when the bin counts vary over several orders of magnitude.

Therefore i started thinking how to tackle this problem from a Bayesian standpoint and came up with the following:

- I take `n` samples and bin them into `N` bins, interpreting them as counts drawn from a multinomial distribution.
- I construct the posterior for the bin probabilities using a Jeffrey's prior, giving me a Dirichlet distribution: $p(\theta|\text{bincounts})=\text{Dirichlet}(\alpha_1+\frac{1}{2},\cdots,\alpha_N+\frac{1}{2}$)

Now my first idea was to compute a credible interval (volume in this case) from the Dirichlet distribution and check if the bin probabilities that i computed from `pdf()` are inside this region to decide on the test result.

But since i have on the order of a thousand bins, directly computing this region for a given significance level is not feasible.

So instead i had the idea to invert the idea and basically compute the significance level (or credibility) given our bin probabilities and Dirichlet distribution by doing the following:

- calculate $\text{threshold}=p(\text{pdf}(P_1,\cdots,P_N)|\text{bincounts})$ by evaluating our posterior with the bin probabilities we got from `pdf()`.
- integrate the indicator function (showing which regions have lower posterior density than our threshold)$$
     I(\theta) = \left\{
       \begin{array}{lr}
         1 :& 0 \lt p(\theta) < \text{threshold} \\
         0 :& \text{otherwise}
       \end{array}
     \right.
  $$
  over the whole support of the Dirichlet posterior density.
- to make this numerically tractable, estimate the integral by using importance sampling over the posterior density itself

This should then result in a number between 0 and 1 showing how much posterior 'volume' has lower density than our threshold giving us a kind of credibility that we can then use to decide if the test fails.

I implemented this in Mathematica and there my algorithm looks like this:

```
DirichletCredibility[observedcounts_, probs_, n_] := Module[
  {dist, mcsamples, pdf, threshold},
  dist = DirichletDistribution[observedcounts + 1/2];
  threshold = PDF[dist, Most[probs]];
  mcsamples = RandomVariate[dist, n];
  N@Mean[Composition[Boole[# <= threshold] &, PDF[dist]] /@ mcsamples]
]
```

I hope i explained well enough what i'm trying to achieve, if not i'm happy to clarify and give more details.

Now what happens when i use this is twofold:
- if i test `DirichletCredibility` with bin counts drawn from a multinomial distribution and bin probabilities which don't match the multinomial probabilities the resulting credibility goes to zero with a high enough number of total samples, which is great!
- if on the other hand i test `DirichletCredibility` with perfectly matching multinomial bin probabilities the result doesn't approach one, but instead tends to a uniform distribution (by repeating the credibility computation with different samples from the multinomial distribution).

My questions are:
- Do you think my methodology can work in principle or does it have major flaws that i should address or consider?
- If this is not feasible how would you tackle the problem in a Bayesian way to get a useful significance test for comparing sampled bin counts with reference probabilities?